# Node.js - Retrieving data from a database (mysql) - delay

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am loading data from the database using mysql drivers for node.js. https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

I want to load data into the array. When I am loading data into the array - there is a delay and the array is empty.

I want to retrieve data and then write the lines - console.log("END QUERY"); console.log(users);

```
var users = [];

client.query(
  'SELECT * FROM users',
  function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

if (results.length > 0) {
          var reader = results[0];
          console.log("ID: " + reader['id']); //ADD string - 'ID: 1'
          users = [reader['id']]
      } 
     }
);

console.log("END QUERY");

console.log(users);
```

OUTPUT:

WRITE LINE:

```
END QUERY
[]
ID: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Node works — using an asynchronous model. First all your code as written executes, including `console.log(users)`. At this point, `users` is an empty array.

Only once all your imperative instructions have executed do callbacks get fired — such as your `selectCb` function. It's only once this callback runs that you can have access to `users`.

This is the entire point and purpose of Node, actually, and it is very important to understand the fundamentals here. You can read more about it at:
http://shinetech.com/thoughts/articles/139-asynchronous-code-design-with-nodejs-

Others have also recommended this video introducing Node from Ryan Dahl:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I

In your specific case, I would move the `console.log("END QUERY")` and `console.log(users)` lines into the body of the `selectCb` function.